# Is it possible to access audio playing from the browser in javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, browser, youtube

Ok, since youtube doesn't allow you the use of the `<audio>` tag, is it possibile to capture the audio that is playing in the browser? (the stream transmitted to hardware).

And a question still relevant, is it possibile to capture the audio of an `<object>` tag? How could i make an `<object>` of a youtube video?

Comment: You can use PHP Media File Info library

Comment: @DmitriyButeiko …that isn't Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

No and no, respectively.

There is no way to capture audio within a web page, especially across origins (e.g, capturing the audio of a YouTube frame, which has the origin `https://youtube.com`).

YouTube used to support an `<object>` embedding method based on Flash. This still exists, but it hasn't been recommended for quite some time, so I won't go into detail. Nor does it help you, as there is no way to capture the audio output from a browser plugin either.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the clarification, but, just to be sure, can an <object> audio be captured? It's from flash, i'm not really sure.

Comment: Ok, so then, using webRTC is there a way to capture the "computer audio", cause you could enable "stereo mix" but not everyone has it enabled.

Comment: No. There is currently no way to capture audio output anywhere in the browser -- the only reason I'm separating out the two is because you asked about them separately.

Comment: Thanks, for your answers, i could implement this by just letting the user download a file and then open it and stream it. I've been succesfull trying this, and it doesn't even ask you, you just "click save" and it does, how about reading a file, is it the same?